# How can I slow down the requests.get() function for web-pages?

Tags: python, html, url, web-scraping, python-requests

I am try to web-scrape owler.com. I already have a list of companies and all I am trying to get is their estimated revenue, employee numbers and headquarters location. Now, I am not trying to spam the website or anything, I don't mind if it takes me like an hour or more to get all the information with slower requests, I just don't want to copy and paste manually because it is very tedious.

I haven't spammed any requests, I have just made one to test and I end up scraping a "Anomaly Detected" page that says "You are a power user moving through this website with superhuman speed." Which means I effectively got denied. Unless I'm missing something, I can't incorporate a sleep somewhere inside the "get()" function because it comes "as is". I have tried the urllib library as an alternative to "requests". However, when I try to scrape with this library, I get back "HTTP Error 405: Not Allowed"

```py
import bs4
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
from requests import get
import time

company = "Rockstar Games"
company = company.lower()

my_url1 = 'https://www.owler.com/company/'+ company.replace(" ", "")

time.sleep(1)
response = get(my_url1)
print("Opening "+my_url1)
print(response.text)

#This is all my code, I used nothing else and I didn't use any loops or spammed anything, I only accessed it once.
```

I am expecting to get back the page so I can access the elements and get the data in it, but I'm getting a captcha page instead. As I said, my intention is not to spam their website, just automate what normally would take me 2 days and would kill a lot of brain cells if I had to do it by hand.

Comment: You can't slow down *one individual request*. You need to slow down the number of requests per minute you make. And for that a `sleep` is exactly what you need.

Comment: My problem is I have NO requests per minute. The code above literally ONLY has ONE request. There is no repetition at all. Even one request I can't do right now, I'm looking for a solution.

Comment: So you're currently on their blacklist. You'll probably have to wait until that expires. Or change your IP address somehow.

Comment: What also might help, but is completely unrelated to the speed issue, is to add more HTTP headers to make your request look like a normal person browsing the web. E.g. the user-agent and some other headers

Comment: I'm not really on their blacklist, I can still access the website normally, it just gives me that page when I use requests. I wouldn't get blacklisted because I didn't spam. @MarkNijboer I don't exactly know what you mean by adding more headers? I haven't come across/know how to do that.

Comment: header additons are very common, just search here for `[python] beautifulsoup header user-agent` and you should find plenty of examples and discussion. Good luck.